# MongoDB - $toString'ing a field of an embedded document array in an aggregation

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of users, and a collection of user orders.
When I retrieve a user, I add all of the orders to the returned structure to make the client-side simpler.
However, I am using NextJS, and thus objects like Date and ObjectId have to be toString'd before reaching the client side.
I did these type conversions and linking between users and orders manually in JS, but doing so in the Mongo driver would clean my code quite a lot.
So now I am looking at aggregation, and it was simple enough to add the orders, however I can't for the life of me figure or google how to refer to the _id field (or others) of the orders to convert it to a string.

This is how the aggregation looks:

```
[
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'orders',
      localField: 'id',
      foreignField: 'user_id',
      as: 'orders',
    },
  },
  { 
    $project: {
      _id: { $toString: '$_id' },
      name: 1,
      'orders._id': { $toString: '???' },
      'orders.order': 1,
    },
  }
]
```

What do I put in the 'orders._id' part? I tried so many combinations, but the best I got is Mongo complaining I am trying to convert an array to a string.

Given a user

```
{ _id: ObjectId('objectId1'), id: 'id', name: 'name' }
```

And an order

```
{ _id: ObjectId('objectId2'), user_id: 'id', order: { ... } }
```

The end result should be

```
{ _id: 'objectId1', name: 'name', orders: [ { _id: 'objectId2', order: { ... } } ] }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `orders` is an array, `orders._id` is an array of all of the `_id` fields from the objects in `orders`.

In order to modify each of the elements you will need to either unwind the array, project, and then group; or use reduce, map, or something similar to modify each element.

Comment: I find it odd, because normally in the projection there is no issue referring to embedded document fields, but it sounds like doing any transformation on them ($toString in this case) would require actual mapping. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Just to help you understand, try projecting `'orders._id': "$orders._id"` to see what that actually returns.